# How to remote power on pc that it is not connected to a lan? It is only connected via usb or PCMCIA with a modem umts/hsdpa

Tags: modem, remote-control

How to remote power on pc that it is not connected to a lan? It is only connected via usb or PCMCIA with a modem umts/hsdpa.

Comment: +1! There is part of USB specification which allows devices to turn on computer when it is off. But first, the computer must support powering devices when it is off.

Comment: Interesting article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280108

Comment: Often PCs can wake up on USB events, e.g from USB keyboards and mice. Dig through the BIOS. Next, you'll need to send a packet to the IP address of the modem, and *maybe* it will wake up the PC. This address is prone to change, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some good comments about this. One other option has sprung to mind which may be relevant if you don't need the wake up to happen automatically AND if you can connect to the LAN port on the PC AND it supports wake on LAN. I was thinking you could connect your PC to a router that supports a wifi dongle and has wake on LAN in its feature set - for example, the Draytek 2820 has a WOL page. If you setup the router with a dynamic name service, like [DYNDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/), you could almost always connect to the router's Web interface and use the WOL page.

Comment: The pc is not connected to a lan.
To connect on internet the pc has only a modem umts/hsdpa connected to  usb or PCMCIA